# Does SyncAdapter support both uploading and downloading during a sync?

Tags: android, synchronization, android-syncadapter

I am trying to write an Android `SyncAdapter` and am a little confused. During a sync (i.e. in `onPerformSync()` ), I want to be able to pull data down from a remote server but also push data up to a remote server (is that a 2-way sync? or is a 2-way sync when the server also initiates a sync?).

Anyway, I am guessing I need to set `android:supportsUploading="true"` in the manifest file. However, from my understanding, the documentation says that this is for uploads only. Is it not possible to do both uploading and downloading in a sync operation with a `SyncAdapter`?.

Thanks.

**Edit:** It looks like the Sample `SyncAdapter` has two way syncing (although I am not 100% sure) - but only from API 11+. I want to support earlier API levels - is this not possible?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know, what protocol you are using to send or receive data, but if you are using http you can easily do both by using a HTTP Get-Request for receiving data and a POST or PUT Request to send data.